# Codeigniter 404 error with Google Adwords due to ?gclid=

Tags: codeigniter, google-ads-api

**Using the latest 1.x (1.7.3) version of CodeIgniter, I get 404 errors on gclid from Google Adwords.** My understanding is that it's because the "?" in the URL that Google Adwords adds. I've read a bunch of answers online, including here, but I couldn't find anything concrete.

The most common are edit the config file to:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

Which solved the gclid problem but killed all my other links. In other words links such as `myDomain.com/something/here/there` would no longer work.

I've also seen solution that say to edit the .htaccess, but most seem to be workarounds that disable proper tracking by google by just redirecting.

So my question is: **What is the proper to allow gclid to go through as well as why is this a good way?**

Comment: "Using the Latest **1.x** version of Codeigniter..."  that might be a problem as the latest is into **2.x**

Comment: I'm sure it was possible to resolve this in 1.x. It's not exactly a new issue...

Comment: just pointing out the conflict in the way you worded your question, and it's never a bad idea to keep software updated.

Comment: I just upgraded a "big" older site from 1.7 to 2.0.2 last night while waiting for my frozen pizza to cook, and had time to spare. @Stephane - It's definitely worth it, and extremely easy. If for no other reason, being able to use `$_GET` properly. The old CI "query strings" have always baffled me as to what their actual purpose is...

Comment: Any good links to what's new in CodeIgniter 2?

Comment: @StephaneGrenier: User Guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html The UG has upgrade instructions and is included in the download from the home page.

Comment: @Stephane Grenier - Updated my answer with a few helpful links...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the **actual** latest version of codeigniter, try using...

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

which is default in the latest releases, instead of ...

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

which changes your url structure to completely using querystrings instead of segment based urls, which is why your other urls are breaking.

**Upgrading information**

[What's different in Codeigniter 2? (the highlights)](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/03/codeigniter-2)

[How to upgrade to Codeigniter 2](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/05/upgrading-to-codeigniter-2.0)

Comment: Thank you for the information, unfortunately this really doesn't help or answer the question because these settings are not available in 1.7.3.

Comment: See the first line... "Using the actual latest version of codeigniter, try using..."

Comment: Using the latest 1.x version, not the latest version ;)

Comment: I've relented and spent all of yesterday and today upgrading. Luckily the site isn't too large and we were able to do it fairly quickly. The validation framework change was the most painful part.

Comment: good! I'm sure you won't regret it.  To be fair, that old validation class has been deprecated for several versions now.

Comment: To be quite honest I don't really see a big advantage yet for what I used it for, but that being said some of the new stuff looks pretty interesting. Hopefully I'll have some time to investigate more in the near future. At least it's done now.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me

```
$config['uri_protocol']    = "PATH_INFO";
```